# Purpose of PHP Debug Pack

Tags: php, debugging, download, package, xdebug

There is a [debug pack](http://windows.php.net/download/) listed under downloads on the official php site.

Is it intended for developers of the php core/runtime and therefore to debug php itself?
Or is it intended for the general php site developer audience and thus to debug *.php files on your website (using xdebug etc)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As explained [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/what-is-the-php-debug-pack-for/4450) it's for developers of PHP.

> I believe it allows you to hook in a debugger for the purpose of hunting down bugs and/or it dumps debugging information when something goes awry. For most bugs, you can just provide a piece of code to reproduce the problem so most bugs do not need that kind of attention.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the case. It contains pdb files to debug php's own components, not *.php files.